# Delete href on bootstrap dropdown and adding "select" to get value marked?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, dropdown

I need a little bit help on a template, where is a pricebox dropdown elements like this

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mhJu.png)

This is the default code of the dropdown price box.

```
 <!--  Various Pricing Dropdown Toggle -->
                            <div class="btn-group btn-block">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">1 Month <b class="text-green">@ $289 </b> <span class="caret"></span>
                                </button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu btn-block" role="menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">3 Years @ $7500 <b class="text-green"></b></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">2 Years @ $5000 <b class="text-green"></b></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">1 Year @ $2600 <b class="text-green"></b></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">6 Months @ $1400 <b class="text-green"></b></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">3 Months @ $750 <b class="text-green"></b></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">1 Month @ $289 <b class="text-green"></b></a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        <!--  End of Various Pricing Dropdown Toggle -->
```

But I dont need the href,  so it can be deleted:

```
<!--  Various Pricing Dropdown Toggle -->
                                <div class="btn-group btn-block">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">1 Month <b class="text-green">@ $289 </b> <span class="caret"></span>
                                    </button>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu btn-block" role="menu">
                                                              <li><a>3 Years @ $5000 <b class="text-green"></b></a></li>
                                <li><a>2 Years @ $3200 <b class="text-green"></b></a></li>
                                <li><a>1 Year @ $1700 <b class="text-green"></b></a></li>
                                <li><a>6 Months @ $900 <b class="text-green"></b></a></li>
                                <li><a>3 Months @ $500 <b class="text-green"></b></a></li>
                                <li><a>1 Month @ $189 <b class="text-green"></b></a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            <!--  End of Various Pricing Dropdown Toggle -->
```

but I need one other thing:

In this example, 1 Month is the default displaying entry. I want, that of any other option is selected (2 Years in example) that this should be display if the dropdown is closing (currently it show only the default option, 1 Month)

Must JavaScript used for those thing? ( i dont need any additional function on this, only that the selection entry/option should be display anstead of default, if leaving the dropdown.

Comment: Did it work before you deleted the hrefs?

Comment: the Problem is ,with a real href, it has redirected asap ot the url.

in case of href #, it goes to the top of the website and no, the option was not marked, if scrolled down, it shows the "default" entry.

Comment: Can elaborate second issue you are facing. And which plugin of Bootstrap toggle you are using.

Comment: Bootstrap v3.3.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (skip the first line if you have already referenced JQuery):

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" 
integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){    
        $(".dropdown-menu li").click(function(){
            $("#button-id").text($(this).text());
            $("#button-id").val($(this).text());
        });
    });
</script>
```

Paste this at the top of your file, and change this line :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">1 Month <b class="text-green">@ $289 </b> <span class="caret"></span>
```

To this:

```
<button type="button" id="button-id" class="btn btn-block btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">1 Month <b class="text-green">@ $289 </b> <span class="caret"></span>
```

For multiple instances, you can replace the script with this:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" 
integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        var selectedListItem = $(".dropdown-menu li");
        selectedListItem.click(function(){
            var button = selectedListItem.closest("div").find(".dropdown-toggle");          
            button.text($(this).text());
            button.val($(this).text());
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Ok, this is a javascript..but i dont how to integrate it on the current dropdown buttons?

Comment: yes, it works...great! Many thanks to you! (one the first box). how can i repeat it for the 3 other boxes? with different button ids?

Comment: i have 4 prices boxes..your solution is working..but it changes the value on all boxes...?!

Comment: ok, i found this, than it works with more than one boxes

`code`
 $(".dropdown-menu").on('click', 'li a', function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().siblings(".btn:first-child").html($(this).text()+' <span class="caret"></span>');
        $(this).parent().parent().siblings(".btn:first-child").val($(this).text());
    }); 
`code`